# HTML background image is zoomed in

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the background image of a section every 5 seconds and I have managed to do so by using JavaScript. But the problem is that images are zoomed in. What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<section id="hero" class="d-flex align-items-end ">
```

JavaScript:

```
function displayNextImage() 
{
    x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
    document.getElementById("imgg").src = images[x];
    document.getElementById("hero").style.background = first[x];
}
        
var first = [], k = -1;
first[0] = "url('1.jpg') no-repeat";
first[1] = "url('2.jpg') no-repeat";
first[2] = "url('3.jpg') no-repeat";
```

Comment: Side note; your `x` modification logic can be reduced to `x = ++x % images.length`

Comment: looks like images are smaller and they are resized to container's height and width

Comment: If you use it like background-image write in css `background-size: cover`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the images sizes don't fit, try to set `background-size` to `cover`:

HTML:

```
<section id="hero" class="d-flex align-items-end ">
```

JS:

```
function displayNextImage(){
  x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
  document.getElementById("imgg").src = images[x];
  document.getElementById("hero").style.background = first[x];
}
    
var first = [], k = -1;
first[0] = "url('1.jpg') no-repeat cover";
first[1] = "url('2.jpg') no-repeat cover";
first[2] = "url('3.jpg') no-repeat cover";
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to see full image size then:

```
first[0] = "url('1.jpg') no-repeat;background-size: contain;";
first[1] = "url('2.jpg') no-repeat;background-size: contain;";
first[2] = "url('3.jpg') no-repeat;background-size: contain;";
```

- also you can set image size by percent/ pixel/ ... like background-size:50%;
  ** if you use contain and if your image size is so large it may cause overflow.

if you want see images related to your element size then:

```
first[0] = "url('1.jpg') no-repeat center center;background-size: cover;";
first[1] = "url('2.jpg') no-repeat center center;background-size: cover;";
first[2] = "url('3.jpg') no-repeat center center;background-size: cover;";
```

- (background-size: cover) will cut the images (if needed) and set to element size.
  ** if you want to use this style, it's better that images have same size and this can be your best choice.

good luck